# avoiding enums as interface identifiers c++ OOP

Tags: c++, oop, templates, plugins

I'm working on a plugin framework using dynamic loaded shared libraries which is based on Eclipse's (and probally other's) extension-point model. All plugins share similar properties (name, id, version etc) and each plugin could in theory satisfy any extension-point. The actual plugin (ie Dll) handling is managed by another library, all I am doing really is managing collections of interfaces for the application.

I started by using an `enum PluginType` to distinguish the different interfaces, but I have quickly realised that using template functions made the code far cleaner and would leave the grunt work up to the compiler, rather than forcing me to use lots of `switch {...}` statements.

The only issue is where I need to specify like functionality for class members - most obvious example is the default plugin which provides a particular interface. A `Settings` class handles all settings, including the default plugin for an interface.

ie `Skin newSkin = settings.GetDefault<ISkin>();`

How do I store the default `ISkin` in a container without resorting to some other means of identifying the interface?

As I mentioned above, I currently use a `std::map<PluginType, IPlugin> Settings::defaults` member to achieve this (where `IPlugin` is an abstract base class which all plugins derive from. I can then `dynamic_cast` to the desired interface when required, but this really smells of bad design to me and introduces more harm than good I think.

would welcome any tips

edit: here's an example of the current use of default plugins

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<ISkin> Skin;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<IPlugin> Plugin;
enum PluginType
{
  skin,
  ...,
  ...
}

class Settings
{
public:
  void SetDefault(const PluginType type, boost::shared_ptr<IPlugin> plugin) {
    m_default[type] = plugin;
  }
  boost::shared_ptr<IPlugin> GetDefault(const PluginType type) {
    return m_default[type];
  }
private:
  std::map<PluginType, boost::shared_ptr<IPlugin> m_default;
};

SkinManager::Initialize()
{
  Plugin thedefault = g_settings.GetDefault(skinplugin);
  Skin defaultskin = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<ISkin>(theskin);
  defaultskin->Initialize();
}
```

I would much rather call the getdefault as the following, with automatic casting to the derived class. However I need to specialize for every class type.

```
template<>
Skin Settings::GetDefault<ISkin>()
{
  return boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<ISkin>(m_default(skin));
}
```

Comment: Can you post some example code of how one might use the defaults?  I'm having a hard time picturing what you're talking about.

Comment: If `IPlugin` is an abstract class, you'll need to store pointers in your map (you'll need to do that anyway, otherwise you'll have slicing issues).

Comment: hi Kristo, have added more of an example

Comment: sorry James I should have specified I was storing shared_ptr(IPlugin). I'm using boost::shared_ptrs to avoid hanging pointers to unloaded Dlls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problem of the enum ? The lack of extensibility.

How to have extensibility and yet retain identification ? You need a full blown object, preferably with a specific type.

Basically you can get away with:

```
class IPluginId
{
public:
  virtual IPluginId* clone() const = 0;
  virtual ~IPluginId();

  bool operator<(const IPluginId& rhs) const { return mId < rhs.mId; }
  bool operator==(const IPluginId& rhs) const { return mId == rhs.mId; }

protected:
  static size_t IdCount = 0;
  IPluginId(size_t id): mId(id) {}
private:
  size_t mId;
};

template <class Plugin>
class PluginId
{
public:
  PluginId(): IPluginId(GetId()) {}
  IPluginId* clone() const { return new PluginId(*this); }
private:
  static size_t GetId() { static size_t MId = ++IdCount; return MId; }
};
```

Now, as for using, it would get:

```
// skin.h

class ISkin;

struct SkinId: PluginId<ISkin> {}; // Types can be forward declared
                                   // Typedef cannot

class ISkin: public IPlugin { /**/ };
```

And now you can get use:

```
class Settings
{
public:
  template <class Plugin>
  void SetDefault(boost::shared_ptr<Plugin> p);

  template <class Plugin>
  boost::shared_ptr<Plugin> GetDefault(const PluginId<Plugin>& id);

private:
  boost::shared_ptr<IPlugin> GetDefault(const IPluginId& id);
};
```

The template version is implemented in term of the non-template one and performs the downcast automatically. There is no way the pointer might be the wrong type because the compiler does the type checking, thus you get away with a `static_cast` :)

I know downcasting all over the place is kind of ugly, but here you just down_cast in one method `GetDefault` and it's type checked at compile time.

Even easier (let's generate the keys on the fly):

```
class Settings
{
public:
  template <class Plugin>
  void SetDefault(const boost::shared_ptr<Plugin>& p)
  {
    mPlugins[typeid(Plugin).name()] = p;
  }

  template <class Plugin>
  boost::shared_ptr<Plugin> GetDefault() const
  {
    plugins_type::const_iterator it = mPlugins.find(typeid(Plugin).name());
    if (it == mPlugins.end()) return boost::shared_ptr<Plugin>();

    return shared_static_cast<Plugin>(it->second);
  }

private:
  typedef std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<IPlugin> > plugins_type;
  plugins_type mPlugins;
};
```

However it's less safe than the first alternative, notably you can put anything there as long as it inherits from `IPlugin`, so you can put `MySkin` for example, and you won't be able to retrieve it through `ISkin` because `typeid(T).name()` will resolve to a different name.

Comment: Hi Matthieu,
thanks for the answer. Starting with the latter, I really like your idea of using the `type_info.name` property, it completely solves my problem in one go. I was actually looking at typeid and the like today and failed to make the leap of faith to realize I could use this as property in many different ways.

However I'm not completely following your first suggestion, if you are still keen [:)] could you provide the implementation for both GetDefault methods?

I'd definitely prefer to do this as a static_cast if possible

Comment: Glad to be of help :) You could perhaps use a `multimap` if you want to have multiple plugins type for a common id value.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but there's cases where I'd like to get the `SkinId` type from an `ISkin` (for example).

Is there any way I can avoid passing the `IPluginId` as a paramater to the `GetDefault` method? ie have the type resolved via the `T` paramater of the return type declaration?

At the moment I have to pass the id like the following

`boost::shared_ptr<ISkin> skin = settings.GetDefault(SkinId());`

Comment: well I've discovered that's impossible, would be akin to return type overloading which isn't allowed. so in both this suggestion and the boost::variant one above I will always need to pass a template parameter

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sequence container of boost::variant instead (untested illustrative code):

```
tyepdef boost::variant<
boost::shared_ptr<ISkin>,
boost::shared_ptr<IPluginType2>,
boost::shared_ptr<IPluginType3>,
etc...> default_t;
std::deque<default_t> defaults;
```

Then:

```
template <class T>
boost::shared_ptr<T> GetDefault() {
    for(std::deque<default_t>::iterator it = defaults.begin(), endIt = defaults.end();
        it != endIt;
        ++it) {
       boost::shared_ptr<T>* result = boost::get< boost::shared_ptr<T> >(*it);
       if( result ) {
           return *result;
       }
    }
    return boost::shared_ptr<T>(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Downcasting may be avoided by using the [Visitor-Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), but this may require substantial refactoring of you architecture. This way, you also do not have to handle the plugins differently. Creating instances of plugins can be done using a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Hope that gives you some starting point. If you wish more details, you have to provide more information on you architecture.

Comment: Hi,
It looks like the visitor-pattern might have been a far better choice given that each plugin could in theory provide any of the interfaces. I'm a bit torn however, as major refactoring would be required to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do something like this.

```
class Settings
{
    public:
        // ...
        template <class T>
        boost::shared_ptr<T> GetDefault()
        {
            // do something to convert T to an object (1)
            return m_default[T_as_an_obj];
        }
        // ....
};

SkinManager::Initialize()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<ISkin> defaultskin = g_settings.GetDefault<ISkin>();
    defaultskin->Initialize();
}
```

Line (1) is the part I think I've seen done before but don't know how to do myself.  Also note that the current implementation returns a null pointer if you pass a type the Settings class hasn't seen yet.  You'll have to account for that in some way.

Comment: Hi Kristo, yeah I always check the pointer after the call to be safe. Line 1 like you say is the hard part, without resorting to switch statements, typeid(T) and the like.